# How to structure a sharepoint site for a college department with different disciplines?

Tags: site-template, sharepoint-library, sharepoint-permissions, content-and-structure

I am tasked with creating a sharepoint site for the IT department of a College. The IT department is made up of three disciplines, Engineering, IT and Environment. Each discipline wants to move their research data to SharePoint, but not share it with other discipline members. However, some Engineering and IT units are part of multiple courses across the 2 disciplines, but Environment does not overlap with other disciplines. How do I design the site and create a site hierarchy and permission groups?

Answer (score 0):

TRY 1
you can create the same access site and build up 3 different document libraries; each one called as the discipline.
you can create groups named as the disciplines or as you want and can put the engineering_group have read permission on document libary called Environment.

TRY 2
you can create the main site as College and three subsites as Engineering, IT and Environment (i prefer the first try)

for build up permission groups you can go in site content-site settings-site permission-Create group

have a try and tell me id my answer matches to you idea.
Lorenzo